# How can i use return in a short if statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to make this:

`if (!token) return res.send("Invalid token!");`

To something like this:

`!token && return res.send("Invalid token!");` or `!token ? res.send("Invalid token!") : null`

(or how can i use return in such cases?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
return !token ? res.send("Invalid token!") : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a check specifically for an empty string over null, which will set a safe guard for empty string.

```
return !token || token==="" ? res.send("Invalid token!") : null;
```

Comment: You should use || not && since you want to check if token doesn't exist or is equal to ""